# What is my name. It is in parts

Tags: riddle

Guess which famous name is the answer to this riddle:

**My first part** is a northern hall, it describes everything.
**My second** comes in many forms such as McCracken, Kreisher and Convy. 
**Part number three** is out of this world.
**My fourth part** is a different kind of one.
**And finally** is what could happen to you in birmingham with ketchup or tea.

**Good Luck!**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Close to the previous answers I think it might be

> Albert Einstein

My first part is a northern hall, it describes everything.

> Al - as pointed out by Bogdan, could describe everything, also probably how would would say 'hall' in a Northern accent.

My second comes in many forms such as McCracken, Kreisher and Convy.

> Bert - as found by Flying_whale

Part number three is out of this world.

> Space - as found by Bogdan

My fourth part is a different kind of one.

> Ein - one of the answers suggested by Flying_whale

And finally is what could happen to you in birmingham with ketchup or tea.

> Stein - which it how you would say 'stain' in a Brummie accent.

In fairness, a lot of this is in the previous answers so I would upvote those too.

Answer (score 7):

Partial answer with Flying whale's help:

> Albert Heinrich?

*My first part is a northern hall, it describes everything.*

> Al - describes everything. Not sure what a northern hall has to do with this.

*My second comes in many forms such as McCracken, Kreisher and Convy.*

> Bert

*Part number three is out of this world.*

> Space. In this case, the space between the first name and last name.

*My fourth part is a different kind of one.*

> H**ein**?

*And finally is what could happen to you in birmingham with ketchup or tea.*

> You get rich.

Answer (score 6):

partial answer
*My second comes in many forms such as McCracken, Kreisher and Convy.* is

> **Bert**: Bert McCracken is a singer, Bert Kreisher is a humorist and Bert Convy is an actor

*My fourth part is a different kind of one*

> maybe 1 in another language: un, uno, ein ?

Comment: you have done well and you two answers so far are correct